# When to use HttpHandlers and HttpModules?

Tags: asp.net, module, handler, httphandler, httpmodule

When exactly to use HttpHandlers and HttpModules?

Can't I write that code in ASPX pages' code behind?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

HttpModule allows you to intercept the request (before it is handled by its handler) and response generated. It can modify both request/response if needed. ASP.NET sessions, profiles, authentication etc is also implemented as HttpModule - these module inspects the request and attach necessary context (e.g. session state based on session cookie) to the request. Such functionality is difficult to achieve via aspx code behind.

HttpHandler is the one responsible for handling the request i.e. to generate HTTP response which often (but not always) means generating some html. The page class (base for aspx) is nothing but http handler (so are other end points such as asmx, ashx, axd). The raw handler (ashx) is useful when you need absolute control over response generation - it would be possible to use aspx instead but then it would unnecessarily involve all default page/control machinery (view-state, post-date, control tree etc).